# ¿Cómo obtener un Image de dart:ui de una imagen de internet?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando insertar una imagen desde internet a mi proyecto, pero quiero que esta se recorte siempre en una misma medida para que nunca haya un OveriSze.

Encontré un [post de github](https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter-samples/blob/master/lib/split_image/main_split_image.dart) que hizo [@diegodeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/66190/diegoveloper) acerca del recorte de imagen en Flutter con el `CustomPainter` donde usa un `AssetImage`. La verdad no comprendí el código al 100%, pero, creo haber entendido masomenos lo que hace cada línea e intenté implementarlo pero esta vez con un `NetworkImage`. Sin embargo esto no da resultado.

Entiendo que esta función asigna a la propiedad `_image`(*propiedad del StateFulWidget donde se encuentra la función*) un `Image` del paquete `dart:ui`, pero en su lugar le asigna `null`, haciendo que no se muestre ninguna imagen donde debería mostrarse. ¿Cuál es el error?
*(Si lo intento con un `AssetImage` en lugar de un `NetworkImage` sigue asignando `null`)*

```
 Future<void> _loadImage()async{
        final networkImage = NetworkImage(widget.product.media[0]);
        final imageKey = await networkImage.obtainKey(const ImageConfiguration());
        final DecoderCallback decodeResize = (Uint8List bytes, {bool? allowUpscaling, int? cacheWidth, int? cacheHeight}) {
          return ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes,targetHeight: cacheHeight, targetWidth: cacheWidth);
        };
        var load = networkImage.load(imageKey, decodeResize);
    
        ImageStreamListener listener = ImageStreamListener((info, err) async {
          setState(() {
            _image = info.image;
          });
        });
            load.addListener(listener);
    }
```

Este es otro intento que hice por obtener el `ui.Image` pero también asigna null:

```
Future<void> getImage(String path) async {
  var completer = Completer<ImageInfo>();
  var img = new NetworkImage(path);
  img.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(ImageStreamListener((info, _) {
    completer.complete(info);
  }));
  ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
  _image = imageInfo.image;
}
```

Aquí es donde asigno el valor devuelto por las funciones a la propiedad `_image`:

```
@override
void initState(){
    // _loadImage();
    // getImage(widget.product.media[0]);
    super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

él código que usé al parecer está desfasado, aquí está la actualización:

```dart
  ui.Image? _image;
  Uint8List? _imageBytes;

  Future<void> _loadImage(String imageUrl) async {
    var networkImage = NetworkImage(imageUrl);
    var completer = Completer<ImageInfo>();
    networkImage
        .resolve(const ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((info, error) {
      completer.complete(info);
    }));
    ImageInfo info = await completer.future;
    final bytesData =
        await info.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    setState(() {
      _image = info.image;
      _imageBytes = bytesData?.buffer.asUint8List();
    });
  }
```

Uso:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadImage('https://stringfixer.com/files/176635397.jpg');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _imageBytes != null
            ? Image.memory(
                _imageBytes!,
                height: 250,
                width: 250,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              )
            : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ahora que me doy cuenta, a tu segundo ejemplo solo le faltó el setState para que refresque el nuevo valor del _image